# Import problem for course UW CSE142 Assignemnt3

Tags: java, awt

I have been follow as course handout words: You should download `DrawingPanel.java` from the class web page and save it in the same folder as your programs. Include the following line of code at the beginning of your class file:

```
  import java.awt.*;
```

And I but them all in my file (you can see what i do on terminal)

```
HW3 / CSE142 lynn$ ls
CafeWall.java       DrawingPanel.java
```

But when i try to coding in Intellij or Jgrasp

```
import java.awt.*;

public class CafeWall {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(650, 450);
    panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphic();
}
```

And I was only to receive the error from compiler:

```
CafeWall.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(650, 450);
    ^
```

So, how can I solve that? Thx in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the first few lines of DrawingPanel.java?

Comment: What command are you executing to compile?

Comment: http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/DrawingPanel.java You can find source code of DrawingPanel.java

Comment: I just want to try will it work or not and click run on JGrasp